# ¿Como sacar el json del suscribe para pasarlo a un objeto?

Tags: json, angularjs-2.0, typescript, angular-datatables, http-get

tengo un Problema.

Sucede que tengo un dato json que recibo de la base de datos, y al entrar al servicio que me trae el json entro al suscribe y le asigno la data json a una variable. pero el Problema esta que el usar la variable a a la que le asigne el json en este caso de llama this.datos, si sale del suscribe ya queda vacía, pero dentro de ella esta con el json que le asigne.

Quisiera saber como hago para que this.datos contenga el json que le asigno en el suscribe para usarlo en otras funciones o operaciones.

Este es el llamado del servicio que trae el json:

```
getDatos(){ 
    this._service.getDatos.subscribe(
        result => {             
            if(result.code = 200){
                 this.datos = result.data;
                 console.log(this.datos);
            }else{
                console.log(result);
            }

        },
        error => {
            console.log(<any>error);
        }
    );
}
```

Este es el servicion get:

```
get getDatos(){
    return this._http.get(this.url+'*').map(res => res.json());
}
```

Lo que quiero es utilizar this.datos con el json asignado a el.

La variable this.datos esta declarada al inicio del componente.

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La varibale this.datos tendrá datos después de que la llamada al servidor termine, sí intentas acceder a la varibale antes de la llamada al servidor esta no tendrá valores ya que la llamada no se ha terminado o no se ha realizado.

Ten en cuenta de que la parte de subscribe es una operación asíncrona, por lo tanto la parte de susbscribe se ejecutará una vez terminada la operación. Después si podrás trabajar con los datos que ha devuelto el servidor.

// puedes hacer de algo así.

```
getDatos(){ 
    this._service.getDatos.subscribe(
        result => utilizarDatos(result),
        error => console.log(<any>error)
    );
}

private function utilizarDatos(result){
    this.datos = result;
    this.datos.forEach((item) => console.log(item));
}
```

Comment: Mil Gracias por tu respuesta me sirvió muchísimo, tambien agradezco tu explicacion y tienes razon.